# Apply full-screen image on some fragments while using NavigationDrawer

Tags: android, android-fragments, navigation-drawer, android-toolbar, android-fullscreen

I am trying to apply background image to some fragments.

I want it look like that(But with a transparent toolbar):
[image]

This is what I have now:

[image]

So, for example, in the home fragment, toolbar will become transparent and will be full screen image.
This is the code:

activity_main.xml:

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <include
            layout="@layout/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/flContent"
            app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nvView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:background="@android:color/white"
        app:menu="@menu/menu_drawer"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header"/>
</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

toolbar.xml:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
    app:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
    android:background="?attr/colorPrimary">
</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

fragment_home.xml:

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.hlsapps.unroutine.HomeFragment">

    <!-- TODO: Update blank fragment layout -->
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:text="Holla home fragment" />

</FrameLayout>
```

Any idea how I can achive that?

Thank you very much,

Haim

Comment: Can you open the problem a little more?

Comment: If i place ImageView in the LinearLayout, it places the image all over the screen and hide the toolbar.

Comment: Can you share your above design code plz

Comment: Do you want to hide toolbar on your `homefragment` ?

Comment: No. Just to make it transparent. But nevermind. I suceeded to fix it. thank you both.